# Problema al compilar con Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, cordova, gradle

Recientemente instalé Ionic pero hasta ahora no he podido compilar ningún proyecto. 
Ésta es la versión de Ionic:

```
PS C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\App1> ionic -v
3.19.0
```

Y ésta es la de cordova:

```
 PS C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\App1> cordova -v
    8.0.0
```

Sí tengo las variables de entorno en Windows del JDK y el SDK.
Al momento de compilar un proyecto nuevo sin nada agregado me marca el siguiente error (ya con la plataforma de android instalada):

```
    PS C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\App1> ionic cordova build android
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[02:19:17]  build dev started ...
[02:19:18]  clean started ...
[02:19:18]  clean finished in 362 ms
[02:19:18]  copy started ...
[02:19:22]  deeplinks started ...
[02:19:22]  deeplinks finished in 603 ms
[02:19:23]  transpile started ...
[02:20:10]  transpile finished in 46.97 s
[02:20:10]  preprocess started ...
[02:20:10]  preprocess finished in 9 ms
[02:20:10]  webpack started ...
[02:20:10]  copy finished in 52.22 s
[02:21:04]  webpack finished in 54.43 s
[02:21:04]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[02:21:22]  sass finished in 17.62 s
[02:21:23]  postprocess started ...
[02:21:24]  postprocess finished in 1.56 s
[02:21:24]  lint started ...
[02:21:25]  build dev finished in 127.26 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\App1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
      > java/io/UncheckedIOException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
(node:5192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code
```

Aquí el archivo donde está el error:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}

->Linea 40 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray
```

Al compilar el mismo proyecto en Android Studio no tengo problemas pero es un poco fastidioso cambiar de Ionic a Android Studio.
Agradezco cualquier aporte

Comment: probaste haciendo un run ? algunas veces el build no funciona y de igual forma el run tambien te genera una apk en modo debug.

Answer (score 0):

Esto pasa al compilar para Android 7+, en mi caso tengo que compilar en la versión de Android 6.3.0.

**Nota:** Con el *SDK Manager* verificar tener instalado el **API 23**.

Para lograr compilar en la versión de Android 6.3.0 es necesario ejecutar el comando:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

Posterior a eliminar la plataforma es necesario indicar a Ionic que la nueva plataforma la queremos en una versión especifica:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

volver a compilar:

```
ionic cordova build android
ionic cordova run android --device
```

**Nota:** Al compilar con *Ionic* se descarga automaticamente el *gradle*.